# How to enable DEBUG level logging with Jetty embedded?

Tags: jetty, slf4j

I'm trying to set the logging level to `DEBUG` in an embedded Jetty instance.

The documentation at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging says to -

> call SystemProperty.set("DEBUG", "true") before calling new
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server().

I'm not sure what the `SystemProperty` class is, it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.  I tried `System.setProperty()`, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: What version of Jetty? What logging framework(s) do you have on the classpath?

Comment: I'm using Jetty 7.5.4 at the moment, but can really use any version.  For logging, I'm using log4j for my non-Jetty code and just letting SLF4J in JEtty default to the NOP logger implementation (it writes to the debug console, which is all I need).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My question was answered on the Jetty mailing list by Joakim Erdfelt:

> You are looking at the old Jetty 6.x docs at docs.codehaus.org.
>
> DEBUG logging is just a logging level determined by the logging
>   implementation you choose to use.
>
> - If you use slf4j, then use slf4j's docs for configuring logging level.   http://slf4j.org/manual.html
> - If you use java.util.logging, use the JVM docs.   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html
> - If you use the built-in StdErrLog, then there is a pattern to follow.
>
> -D{classref}.LEVEL={level}
>
> Where {classref} is the class reference you want to set the level on,
>   and all sub-class refs. and {level} is one of the values ALL, DEBUG,
>   INFO, WARN
>
> Example:
>   -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO  - this will enable INFO level logging for all jetty packages / classes.
>   -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.io.LEVEL=DEBUG - this will enable DEBUG level logging for IO classes only
>   -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.servlet.LEVEL=ALL - this will enable ALL logging (trace events, internally ignored exceptions, etc..) for servlet
>   packages.
>   -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.LEVEL=ALL - this will enable level ALL+ on the specific class only.

Answer (score 28):

Add this

```
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog 
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG
```

[image: Snap of Eclipse Configuration]

Comment: +1, this is the only solution that worked for me, although I don't understand why the first option is needed for the second one to work...

Comment: It took me 4 hours to find this, but here it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

In case you just want to quickly get log messages to stderr add something like this to java command line:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog -D{classref}.LEVEL=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this snippet to enable logging:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog;
 .
 .
 .
StdErrLog logger = new StdErrLog();
logger.setDebugEnabled(true);
Log.setLog(logger);
```